# Access Row By Row Percent of Total

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Sorry if this is a dumb question everyone, but I'm stuck on something that seems pretty simple.

If I create SQL like this:

```
Weights: [Volume]/2792
```

I get the row by row percent of the total.

[image]

However, there's no way I'm going to hard-code the total, so I really want to setup my query like this:

```
Weights: [Volume]/sum([Volume])
```

However, that gives me this.

[image]

Can someone show me how to dynamically sum the field 'Weights' so I can get the percent of each record?

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT tblOffices.ServiceID, tblOffices.Branch, tblOffices.Volume, [Volume]/Sum([Volume]) AS Weights
FROM tblOffices
GROUP BY tblOffices.ServiceID, tblOffices.Branch, tblOffices.Volume;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the sum in a subquery/stacked query and then using the result in your expression? If you post your sql we can adapt it. The way you are doing it now, your `Sum` function is not technically aggregating because it's calculating on the row level instead of the domain level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is 2 queries or a query with a sub query. if you are not familiar with sub queries, do 2 queries like this:

QRY1

```
SELECT Sum([VOLUME]) AS [Total Volume] 
FROM yourTable
```

This will give you the sum of all the volumes.

Then build another query, that uses the result of QRY1 as a value for your calculation.

QRY2

```
SELECT Yourtable.[Volume] AS Vol, YourTable.[Volume]/QRY1.[Total Volume] AS Weight
FROM YourTable,TEST1;
```

to display as a percentage multiple by 100 or set the format as percentage.

Comment: Yeap, that works.  There should be a way of doing this using just one Query, but nothing that I tried actually worked.  At least I got this working.  Thanks.

Comment: There is, just google how to use sub queries. Its essentially the same but this is easier to troubleshoot if you make changes along the way.